# Can We Redirect Custom Domain Back To Blogspot Domain

Tags: blogger, domain

I want to redirect my custom domain, www name. com to my old blogspot domian for example http: // name.blogspot. com. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether your domain registrar provides this option.  It is not something you can set in Blogger.